# Join Error with integer64 keys

Tags: r, data.table

I am getting an unexpected error when trying to join tables that have a column of integer64 values as the primary key. The following illustrates the issues --

```
Keys as int
-----------
x <- data.table(c1=c(1,2,3), c3=c(10,20,30))
z <- data.table(c1=c(1,2), c2=c(100,200))

setkey(x, c1)
setkey(z, c1)

> z[x]          # Join works fine

   c1  c2 c3
1:  1 100 10
2:  2 200 20
3:  3  NA 30


As integer64
------------

library(bit64)
x[,c1:=as.integer64(c1)]
z[,c1:=as.integer64(c1)]

setkey(x, c1)
setkey(z, c1)

> z[x]       # Same join, but generates error message

Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
Join results in 6 rows; more than 3 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values 
in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try 
including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the 
large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. 
Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and 
datatable-help for advice.
```

Any thoughts on what the issue could be ? I am getting the same error on much larger tables. As a workaround I have had to cast the integer64 values to character after which it works fine.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

... 
other attached packages:
[1] bit64_0.9-2       bit_1.1-10        cluster_1.14.4    skmeans_0.2-4     ggplot2_0.9.3.1  
[6] data.table_1.8.11
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please file a bug report

Comment: The error message is a sign of a deeper problem with integer64, as `z[x, allow.cartesian = TRUE]` shows what the merge is trying to do

Comment: Filed: https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5018&group_id=240&atid=975

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273321/large-integers-in-data-table-grouping-results-different-in-1-9-2-compared-to-1. You can try 1.9.3 (on RForge only now, not CRAN)

Comment: @xbsd, as answer now works, please consider accepting it so that question doesn't appear anymore unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer an open question. This is now (1.9.5) handled as expected.
Your join on integer64 columns returns same result as join on numeric fields.