# Grouping very small numbers (e.g. 1e-28) and 0.0 in data.table v1.8.10 vs v1.9.2

Tags: r, debugging, data.table, frequency

I noticed that frequency tables created by data.table in R seem not to distinguish between very small numbers and zero? Can I change this behavior or is this a bug?

Reproducible example:

```
>library(data.table)   
DT <- data.table(c(0.0000000000000000000000000001,2,9999,0))    
test1 <- as.data.frame(unique(DT[,V1]))   
test2 <-  DT[, .N, by = V1]
```

As you can see, the frequency table (test2) will not recognize the differences between 0.0000000000000000000000000001 and 0 and put both observations in the same class.

Data.table version: 1.8.10
R: 3.02

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is worth reading [R FAQ 7.31](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html) and thinking about the accuracy of floating point represenations.

I can't reproduce this in the current cran version (1.9.2). using

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

My guess that the change in behaivour will be related to this news item.

> o  Numeric data is still joined and grouped within tolerance as before but instead of tolerance
>        being sqrt(.Machine$double.eps) == 1.490116e-08 (the same as base::all.equal's default)
>        the significand is now rounded to the last 2 bytes, apx 11 s.f. This is more appropriate
>        for large (1.23e20) and small (1.23e-20) numerics and is faster via a simple bit twiddle.
>        A few functions provided a 'tolerance' argument but this wasn't being passed through so has
>        been removed. We aim to add a global option (e.g. 2, 1 or 0 byte rounding) in a future release.

---

**Update from Matt**

Yes this was a deliberate change in v1.9.2 and `data.table` now distinguishes `0.0000000000000000000000000001` from `0` (as user3340145 rightly thought it should) due to the improved rounding method highlighted above from [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable).

I've also added the `for` loop test from Rick's answer to the test suite.

Btw, #5369 is now implemented in v1.9.3 (although neither of these are needed for this question) :

> o  bit64::integer64 now works in grouping and joins, #5369. Thanks to
>   James Sams for highlighting UPCs.
>
> o  New function setNumericRounding() may be used to reduce to 1 byte
>   or 0 byte rounding when joining to or grouping columns of type 'numeric', #5369.
>   See example in ?setNumericRounding and NEWS item from v1.9.2.
>   getNumericRounding() returns the current setting.

Notice that rounding is now (as from v1.9.2) about the accuracy of the *significand*; i.e. the number of significant figures. `0.0000000000000000000000000001 == 1.0e-28` is accurate to just 1 s.f., so the new rounding method doesn't group this together with `0.0`.

In short, the answer to the question is : upgrade from v1.8.10 to v1.9.2 or greater.

Comment: Matt, thank you for your detailed answer. And more generally, thank you for writing and updating data.table - in my view one of the most important packages for R (in particular if you need to deal with larger amounts of data). Thanks to the whole team working on this!