# Rounding milliseconds of POSIXct in data.table v1.9.2 (ok in 1.8.10)

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I have a weird result for my `data.table` v1.9.2 :

```
DT
                 timestamp
1: 2013-01-01 17:51:00.707
2: 2013-01-01 17:51:59.996
3: 2013-01-01 17:52:00.059
4: 2013-01-01 17:54:23.901
5: 2013-01-01 17:54:23.914

str(DT)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ timestamp: POSIXct, format: "2013-01-01 17:51:00.707" "2013-01-01 17:51:59.996" "2013-01-01 17:52:00.059" "2013-01-01 17:54:23.901" ...
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "timestamp"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

When I apply the `duplicated()` function I get the following result:

```
duplicated(DT)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

It is weird to get the 5th line equal to the 4th.
This also blocks me from joining tables in R. Does is have something to do with POSIXct type?

DT on skydrive : [DT](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E718AC7D0275FC4!1566&authkey=!AFWwwtYB1hdTtIY&ithint=file,.RData)

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like `duplicated.data.table` can't deal with fractional seconds. You could do something like `DF[, chartime:=as.character(timestamp)]` as a work-around.

Comment: OK, so who knows a workaround. It still has to be a data.table and preferable POSIXct type for the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I reproduced your result with v1.9.2.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(timestamp=c(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:51:00.707"),
                             as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:51:59.996"),
                             as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:52:00.059"),
                             as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:54:23.901"),
                             as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:54:23.914")))

options(digits.secs=3)  # usually placed in .Rprofile

DT
                 timestamp
1: 2013-01-01 17:51:00.707
2: 2013-01-01 17:51:59.996
3: 2013-01-01 17:52:00.059
4: 2013-01-01 17:54:23.901
5: 2013-01-01 17:54:23.914

duplicated(DT)
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

---

**Update from v1.9.3 from Matt**

There was a change to rounding in v1.9.2 which affected milliseconds of POSIXct. More info here :

[Grouping very small numbers (e.g. 1e-28) and 0.0 in data.table v1.8.10 vs v1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290544/grouping-very-small-numbers-e-g-1e-28-and-0-0-in-data-table-v1-8-10-vs-v1-9-2)

[Large integers in data.table. Grouping results different in 1.9.2 compared to 1.8.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273321/large-integers-in-data-table-grouping-results-different-in-1-9-2-compared-to-1)

So, the workaround now available in v1.9.3 is :

```
> setNumericRounding(1)   # default is 2
> duplicated(DT)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Hope you understand why the change was made and agree that we're going in the right direction.

Of course, you shouldn't have to call `setNumericRounding()`, that's just a workaround.

I've filed a new item on the tracker :

[#5445  numeric rounding should be 0 or 1 automatically for POSIXct](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5445&group_id=240&atid=975)

Comment: I uploaded DT on skydrive:
[link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E718AC7D0275FC4!1566&authkey=!AFWwwtYB1hdTtIY&ithint=file%2c.RData)

Comment: going to try to grab 1.9.2 of `data.table` since I just tried it with your saved DT and got the same result as my example showed (i.e. all `FALSE`)

Comment: hey! I had 1.8.11 installed prior to your example and I just installed 1.9.2 and completely reproduced the error. Time to file a bug report!

Comment: in terms of a workaround, can you do a temporary conversion to character, do the `duplicated()` call then convert back? it shouldn't have the same problem with comparison as character.

Comment: I will try to use the character conversion.
However I don't know how to file a bug report. I will let the others do it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this thread counts as one. @Arun is one of the co-developers of `data.table` so there's plenty of info here.

Comment: @misha_dodic, I've already linked to the FR in your post. When that's fixed, this issue'll go away. I've also added this post in that FR. So, all is well. Thanks hrbrmstr for the tag.