# Rounding POSIXct in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, posixct

Using the same data from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356957/rounding-milliseconds-of-posixct-in-data-table-v1-9-2-ok-in-1-8-10), there is a problem with rounding date-times to the second in data.table v1.9.2.

```
require(data.table)
options(digits.secs=3)  # usually placed in .Rprofile
DT <- data.table(timestamp=c(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:51:00.707"),
                             as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:51:59.996"),
                             as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:52:00.059"),
                             as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:54:23.901"),
                             as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 17:54:23.914")))
DT
DT[ , round(timestamp)]  # looks good
DT[ , timestamp_rounded := round(timestamp)]  # does not work
DT[ , timestamp_rounded := round(timestamp, units="secs")]  # does not work
DT
#                   timestamp timestamp_rounded
# 1: 2013-01-01 17:51:00.707       1,0,0,24,24
# 2: 2013-01-01 17:51:59.996    51,52,52,54,54
# 3: 2013-01-01 17:52:00.059    17,17,17,17,17
# 4: 2013-01-01 17:54:23.901         1,1,1,1,1
# 5: 2013-01-01 17:54:23.914         0,0,0,0,0
```

I found a solution using `lubridate`:

```
require(lubridate)
DT[ , timestamp_rounded := round_date(timestamp, "second")]  # works
```

Is there a data.table approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there a data.table approach"? You're using data.table aren't you?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question but `IDateTime` in the `data.table` package might be of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`round.POSIXt` produces `POSIXlt` objects and `data.table` (intentionally) does not store `POSIXlt` objects, because they are unnecessarily large. The solution is then to simply convert back to `POSIXct`:

```
DT[, timestamp_rounded := as.POSIXct(round(timestamp))]
#                 timestamp   timestamp_rounded
#1: 2013-01-01 17:51:00.707 2013-01-01 17:51:01
#2: 2013-01-01 17:51:59.996 2013-01-01 17:52:00
#3: 2013-01-01 17:52:00.059 2013-01-01 17:52:00
#4: 2013-01-01 17:54:23.901 2013-01-01 17:54:24
#5: 2013-01-01 17:54:23.914 2013-01-01 17:54:24
```