# Count of data by Sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

My data looks like:

```
 ID   category
101          A
101          B
101          C
102          A
103          B
103          C
```

I would like the result like:

```
 ID   category Count 
101          A     3
101          B     3
101          C     3
102          A     1
103          B     2
103          C     2
```

I have tried something like:

```
data<-sqldf("select *,count(ID) as count from data group by ID")
```

It is showing the output as:

```
 ID   category  count
101          C      3
102          A      1
103          C      2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Count:=.N, ID]
#    ID category Count
#1: 101        A     3
#2: 101        B     3
#3: 101        C     3
#4: 102        A     1
#5: 103        B     2
#6: 103        C     2
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Count=n())
```

Or using `base R`

```
 df1$Count <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(ID), ID, FUN=length))
```

Comment: It is not working for bigger ID's for example 800000000000003, 800000000000002 by data.table @akrun

Comment: @karthikkumarmannava  Can you try after reading it as `character` column?

Comment: @karthikkumarmannava  What about the `dplyr` method? Did you meant that it is working with numeric class itself?

Comment: @karthikkumarmannava  The issue may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273321/large-integers-in-data-table-grouping-results-different-in-1-9-2-compared-to-1)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I switched to using character for columns with large integer values and it is working fine .@akrun

Answer (score 2):

For an all SQL solution left join the output of your code (except omit `category`) with the original data frame like this:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from data
       left join (select ID, count(ID) as count from data group by ID)
       using (ID)")
```

giving:

```
   ID category count
1 101        A     3
2 101        B     3
3 101        C     3
4 102        A     1
5 103        B     2
6 103        C     2
```

**Note:** Here is the input data in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "ID   category
101          A
101          B
101          C
102          A
103          B
103          C"
data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Base `R` approach:

```
transform(df, count=table(ID)[as.character(ID)])
#   ID category count
# 1 101        a     3
# 2 101        b     3
# 3 101        c     3
# 4 102        a     1
# 5 103        b     2
# 6 103        c     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another two options using the base package:

1.

```
merge(df, table(df$ID), by.x = "ID", by.y = "Var1")
```

Output:

```
   ID category Freq
1 101        A    3
2 101        B    3
3 101        C    3
4 102        A    1
5 103        B    2
6 103        C    2
```

2.Very similiar to the one proposed by akrun

```
df$count <- ave(df$ID, df$ID, FUN=length)
df
```

Output:

```
   ID category count
1 101        A     3
2 101        B     3
3 101        C     3
4 102        A     1
5 103        B     2
6 103        C     2
```